# Visual Studio Test Explorer does not discover jasmine tests

Tags: visual-studio-2012, jasmine, chutzpah

I have jasmine tests that run through the Chutzpah context menu extension (Run JS tests). However they do not get discovered by the Test Explorer and when I right-click and select Run Tests, the output from "Tests" gives me this:

```
System.ArgumentException: The directory name  is invalid.
   at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher..ctor(String path, String filter)
   at Chutzpah.VS11.EventWatchers.TestFilesUpdateWatcher.AddWatch(String path)
   at Chutzpah.VS2012.TestAdapter.ChutzpahTestContainerDiscoverer.UpdateTestContainersAndFileWatchers(IEnumerable`1 files, Boolean isAdd)
   at Chutzpah.VS2012.TestAdapter.ChutzpahTestContainerDiscoverer.GetTestContainers()
   at Chutzpah.VS2012.TestAdapter.ChutzpahTestContainerDiscoverer.get_TestContainers()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.TestContainerDiscovererExtension.GetSortedContainers(ITestContainerDiscoverer discoverer)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.TestContainerProvider.GetContainersFromDiscoverer(ITestContainerDiscoverer discoverer)
No tests found to run.
```

Here's my chutzpah.json file also:

```
{
    "Framework": "jasmine",
    "FrameworkVersion": "2",
    "TestHarnessLocationMode": "SettingsFileAdjacent",
    "References": [
        { "Path": "../../DIB.MemberCatalog/lib/dust/dust-full.js" },
        { "Path": "../../DIB.MemberCatalog/lib/dust-helpers/dust-helpers.js" },
        { "Path": "../../DIB.MemberCatalog/lib/harvey/harvey.js" },
        { "Path": "../../DIB.MemberCatalog/lib/hopscotch/js/hopscotch.js" },
        { "Path": "../../DIB.MemberCatalog/lib/jquery/jquery-1.11.1.js" },
        { "Path": "../../DIB.MemberCatalog/lib/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js" },
        { "Path": "../../DIB.MemberCatalog/lib/jquery-validate/jquery.validate.js" },
        { "Path": "../../DIB.MemberCatalog/lib/knockout/knockout-3.1.0.js" },
        { "Path": "../../DIB.MemberCatalog/lib/knockout-mapping/knockout.mapping.js" },
        { "Path": "../../DIB.MemberCatalog/lib/knockout-validation/knockout.validation.js" },
        { "Path": "../../DIB.MemberCatalog/lib/lightbox/js/lightbox.js" },
        { "Path": "../../DIB.MemberCatalog/lib/respond/respond.js" },
        { "Path": "../../DIB.MemberCatalog/Scripts/jquery.qtip.min.js" },
        { "Path": "../../DIB.MemberCatalog/Scripts/json2.min.js" },
        { "Path": "../../DIB.MemberCatalog/Scripts/jquery.cookie.js" },
        { "Path": "../../DIB.MemberCatalog/Scripts/jquery.hoverIntent.min.js" },
        { "Path": "../../DIB.MemberCatalog/Scripts/jquery.lazyload.min.js" },
        { "Path": "../../DIB.MemberCatalog/Scripts/changecheck.js" },
        { "Path": "../../DIB.MemberCatalog/Scripts/stickytable.js" },
        { "Path": "../../DIB.MemberCatalog/Scripts/superalert.js" },
        { "Path": "../../DIB.MemberCatalog/Scripts/core.js" },

        { "Path": "prepare.js" },
        { "Path": "engine.js" }
    ],

    "Tests": [
        { "Path": "tests" }
    ],

    "CodeCoverageIncludes": [],
    "CodeCoverageExcludes": []
}

Solution structure:
DIB.MemberCatalog
  -Testing
    - DIB.MemberCatalog.Tests.JS
      - data
      - lib
        - jasmine-2.0.0
          - (jasmine files, boot, console, jasmine)
      - tests
        - testfiles.js
      - chutzpah.json
  -DIB.MemberCatalog
    - (more...)
```

I've scoured the internet and can't find a solution.

Comment: You probably don't want rooted paths (paths that start with `/`), as Chutzpah will be looking in your drive root for these files.

Comment: Thanks, question updated. Still not the fix though.

Comment: What's your solution structure like?

Comment: You might want to add the Include property to your Tests array: something like:

 { "Path": "tests", "Include": "*Spec.js" }


If that still doesn't help I did notice that installing Resharper on a new dev machine caused the Chutzpah test discovery to stop working.  If you've installed this recently you may want to remove it and see if this clears up your issue.

Comment: @jessehouwing - I've updated the question with my structure. njappboy - tried that, didn't change anything.

Comment: I've even tried a very basic setup under my project as shown in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=meJ94rAN7P8, and it still doesn't discover the tests. I feel like something is getting in the way of it.

Comment: Solved it, don't name a project with a .JS at the end. Changed the project name and all the tests were discovered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by changing my test project name from DIB.MemberCatalog.Tests.JS to DIB.MemberCatalog.Tests.Client. Confusion happens when the project has the javascript file extension at the end of the project name.